# Show (make editable) Elements of a single Row with JQuery in JSF2

Tags: jquery, html, jsf-2, primefaces

my goal is to have an editable HTML-table with N rows and M columns. Therefor I like to offer a solution which shows all Elements of ONE row as editable while the other rows remain as simple outputText. So far I'm able to show the hidden fields, if I know the exact ID of the Row. An there is the problem ... I don't know the ID as you know JSF generates its own IDs and I do have N (unspecific number of) rows.

This is my JSF/HTML code (Primefaces is also integrated)

```
    <h:panelGroup id="table" layout="block" styleClass="ui-datatable ui-widget bearbeiten-ergebnisse__tabelle">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <th class="ui-state-default">
          <h:outputText value="Editieren" />
         </th>
         <ui:repeat
           var="column" value="#{AuswahlBean.selectedMetaDataVersionColums}">
           <th class="ui-state-default">
             <h:outputText value="#{func:getColumnNameSplit(column.header)}" escape="false"/>
           </th>
         </ui:repeat>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
         <ui:repeat id="rowTable" 
           var="rows" value="#{AuswahlBean.selectedMetaDataVersionResultSet}">
           <tr
               id="#{component.clientId}" 
               class="ui-widget-content clickable-row">
               <td class="row-operation">
                   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-row-edit" value="edit" />
                   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-row-save hide-field" value="save " />
                   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-row-cancel hide-field" value="cancel" />
               </td>
               <ui:repeat
                 var="column" value="#{AuswahlBean.selectedMetaDataVersionColums}">
                 <td>
                   <!-- Zelleninhalt, der nicht-editierbar ist -->
                   <h:outputText
                       value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                       styleClass="ui-outputfield"
                       rendered="#{column.typeText}"/>
                   <h:outputText
                     value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                     styleClass="ui-outputfield"
                     rendered="#{column.typeNumeric}" >
                     <f:converter converterId="DwhNumberConverter"/>
                   </h:outputText>
                   <h:outputText
                     value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                     styleClass="ui-outputfield"
                     rendered="#{column.typeDate}">
                     <f:converter converterId="DwhDateConverter"/>
                   </h:outputText>

                   <!-- Zelleninhalt, der nicht-editierbar ist -->
                   <p:inputText
                       rendered="#{column.typeText}"
                       value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                       styleClass="hide-field"
                       required="true"
                       requiredMessage="Überprüfungsfehler: Eine Eingabe wird erwartet."/>
                   <p:inputText
                       rendered="#{column.typeNumeric}"
                       value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                       styleClass="hide-field"
                       required="true"
                       requiredMessage="Überprüfungsfehler: Eine Zahl wird erwartet."
                       converter="DwhNumberConverter">
                       <p:ajax event="valueChange" async="TRUE"
                         update="@this :theForm:msg" />
                     </p:inputText>
                   <p:calendar
                       rendered="#{column.typeDate}"
                       value="#{rows[column.property]}"
                       styleClass="calendar-inputfield hide-field"
                       pattern="dd.MM.yyy"
                       required="true"
                       requiredMessage="Ein Datum wird erwartet. Bitte geben Sie in Datum im Format tt.mm.jjjj an."
                       converter="DwhDateConverter">
                       <p:ajax event="valueChange" async="TRUE"
                       update="@this :theForm:msg"/>
                   </p:calendar>
                 </td>
               </ui:repeat>
           </tr>
         </ui:repeat>
       </tbody>
       </table>
      </h:panelGroup>
```

And here the JavaScript snipet.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   // Show the editable Row
   $('.ui-row-edit').click(function(event){
     var editableRowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     var fixedIdForJquerySelector = editableRowId.replace(/\:/g, '\\\\:');

     showInputFields(fixedIdForJquerySelector);
   });
   function showInputFields(rowID) {
     alert(rowID);
     $("#"+rowID+" .ui-outputfield").css("color","red");
     /* $('#' + rowID + ' .ui-inputfield').removeClass('hide-field');
     $('#' + rowID + ' .calendar-inputfield').removeClass('hide-field');
     $('#' + rowID + ' .ui-outputfield').addClass('hide-field');
     $('#' + rowID + ' .ui-row-edit').addClass('hide-field');
     $('#' + rowID + ' .ui-row-save').removeClass('hide-field');
     $('#' + rowID + ' .ui-row-cancel').removeClass('hide-field'); */
   }

    </script>
```

For any reasons the ID-expression isn't accepted as a jQuery selector. Or to be precise, the error is that whatever follows the colon (in the regex ':') is being read as a CSS-pseudo-class. The following is the error message of the firefox console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: rowTable\

Someone could expect that this is the regular behavior BUT if I hardcode the same selector (ID) like this

```
    $("#theForm\\:rowTable\\:0 .ui-outputfield").css("color","red");
```

instead of

```
    $("#"+rowID+" .ui-outputfield").css("color","red");
```

I'll get the wanted behavior.

And to get to the point:
a) Does anyone know why the selector won't work?
b) Does anyone have an other solution for editing a single row including converters?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

**The jQuery-solution with help by @Denish.** Even though I still don't know why the row-ID isn't accepted as a jQuery-selector (Any hints on that, just for the background know-how?).

```
    $('.ui-row-edit').click(function(event) {
        var editableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        showInputFields(editableRow);
    });

    function showInputFields(rowObject) {
        rowObject.find('.ui-inputfield').toggleClass('hide-field');
        rowObject.find('.ui-outputfield').toggleClass('hide-field');
        // and so on for all necessary CSS-classes
    }
```

Comment: did u have any unique id for every td in particular row

Comment: @Dinesh Initially I didn't set any IDs for <td> or <tr> Tags. For the <tr>-tag I used the clientID to have a simpler control of the  wanted row. But if there's a solution without setting an ID I would highly appreciate it. On the other hand if your solution relies on  IDs for <td>-tags then you can be sure that JSF does this OR I use the same solution as for the <tr>-tag `id="#{component.clientId}"`.

Comment: k friend i cannot understand your question but i thick while user can click the td then u need show text box and capure the value may i right

Comment: @Dinesh Partially you're right. If the user clicks on a row (or an element in the row) the whole row should be editable (show inputfields), capture the new values, convert and validate them and finally save all.

Comment: just do one thing u hide the input type field while user click u can show the textbox do you want code for this

Comment: @Dinesh Yes! But all elements of the same row should be shown.

Comment: you not getting solution still now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML CODE (DEMO :  http://jsbin.com/vacul/1/edit)

```
 <table>
   <tr>
         <td class="Bover"></td>
         <td class="Orun"></td>
         <td>
            <input type="button" value="EDIT" class="Bedit" />
        </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.Bedit').click(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
    var btnvalue = $(this).val();
    if (btnvalue == "EDIT") {

      var data = dad.find('.Bover').text();
      var data1 = dad.find('.Orun').text();

      dad.find('.Bover').text('');
      dad.find('.Orun').text('');


        dad.find('.Bover').append('<input type="text" class="hide" name="BOvers" value='+ data +' />');
      dad.find('.Orun').append('<input type="text" class="hide" name="BRuns" value='+ data1 +' />');

        $(this).val('NEXT');
    }
    else {
        var Bover = dad.find('[name="BOvers"]').val();
        dad.find('.Bover').text(Bover);
        var Orun = dad.find('[name="BRuns"]').val();
        dad.find('.Orun').text(Orun);

        dad.find('.hide').hide();

        $(this).val('EDIT');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank your sir, you showed me the trick. With the help of jQuery-function `find([selector])` I can get it done. Thanks again friend, after 2 days of work I finally have a solution ;-)
I post my final solution underneath my question.

Comment: I almost found the solution by myself with jQuery-function `children([selector])` but made a mistake that I looked for the class in the 1st level child (<td>-tags).
To make it clear, I used `rowObject.children('.ui-inputfield').removeClass('hide-field')` instead of `rowObject.children().children('.ui-inputfield').removeClass('hide-field')`. I thought the children-function would search through all children of the DOM-tree. Maybe that solution will help some others even though the solution above is the more elegant one.

Comment: you not getting solution still now

Comment: What do you mean by "you not getting solution still now"?
I marked your answer as a solution days ago...